# Trying to update values of an SQLite database from an Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

Using the following code I can't upgrade the data in the database:

```
public void modification(int pos) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
            "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues record = new ContentValues();
    record.put(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.ALARM_HOUR, alarmList.get(pos).getHour());
    record.put(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.ALARM_DATE, alarmList.get(pos).getDate());
    record.put(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.ALARM_ACTIVE, 1);
    int numOfRows = db.update("alarm", record, "id=" + alarmList.get(pos).getId(), null);
    db.close();

}
```

The method `update` is returning 0 when it should return the number of rows affected and I have already checked that the id I put in the method exists in the database. It should return 1.
¿Does anyone know where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try this way `db.update("alarm", record, "id"+ "='" +alarmList.get(pos).getId() + "'",null);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not working

Comment: Some questions (1) are you getting a valid writabledatabase? (2) alarm list is an instance variable - are you getting the right values from the list? (3) you don't return the value for numOfRows so how do you know its 0? (4) check the syntax of your where clause - its linked to other values from alarmList which may be incorrect.

Comment: I have found the problem with your help @Rarw. The name of the database I set here is "administration" but it should be something different. I had checked all the other stuff, but not that. Thanks a million.